Automatically lock cells
I have been trying to create coding to automatically lock cells down immediately after entering data.
I have been trying to create coding to automatically lock cells down immediately after entering data.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C54:G150")
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1214"
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Locked = True
End If
Next
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1214"
End Sub

It blocked changes from cell c54 to g58 and then stopped. Can anyone see where i have gone wrong?

Worth to test Target range with Intersect function not to run the whole code when changes were made to other cells then the specified range. Maybe cells are empty after it so they will not be locked. If you have already protected the sheet how do you want to change cell on it?

I want it so people can go and add data but also show that there can't be back dating input if missed if that makes sense.

I am afraid it does not make too much sense... Do you want allowing that only unlocked cells to be modified? If so, it would be good to only lock the changed target. NOT to iterate between the whole range. And also limit your event action in case of changing a cell in the respective range, as suggested above... If not, a licked cell in a protected sheet cannot be changed at all...

Sorry its my first time working with VBA so im learning as i go... I've created a sheet so that staff can log in a time of when they arrive and when they leave. The purpose i am looking for is for the CELL that has had data added to lock after that but keep the sheet open continuously for others to input their times as well if that makes sense.

So if you can imagine column C will have names being input, Column D will have the date, Column E will have the time, Column F will have another date and Column G will have time finishing. The sheet will be unlocked for people to add their dates and times but then i want it to lock the cell down once they have

Tim, I know you are working on a VBA solution but you might also consider looking into office 365 forms which could send each entry to an excel sheet. I used this approach and had the form open automatically when users logged into my lab computers and I also had the form on an ipad on the wall.

What does "...and then stopped" mean? If an error occurred, which one (number and description)? When you test if a cell is blank with If cell.Value <> "" Then, a type-mismatch error will occur if the cell contains an error value. It is safer to use If CStr(cell.Value) <> "" Then. Also, you should use For Each cell In rng.Cells when looping through cells,

The coding worked fine for a few cells, by which i mean it let you enter data and then locked after... Then it kept the cells open after data entry without locking the cell.

If cell. Value  "" Then

This mod will enable to add some data in empty cells and then lock the cell. Requires that the empty sheet (at creating the sheet) cells Locked property is not checked.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Dim rng As Range
'Set rng = Range("C54:G150")
'For Each cell In rng
'If cell.value <> "" Then
'cell.Locked = True
'End If
'Next
If Target <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Target.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
End Sub



A Worksheet Change: Lock Non-Blank Changed Cells
Main: Sheet Module e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C54:G150"
    Const P_WORD As String = "1214"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet (in a sheet module).
    With Me
        
        ' Reference the target range.
        Dim trg As Range: Set trg = .Range(TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS)
        
        ' Reference the changed target cells ('irg'), the target cells ('trg')
        ' that intersect with all changed cells ('Target') in the worksheet.
        Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
        If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells have changed
        
        ' Reference the changed target cells that are not blank.
        Dim iurg As Range: Set iurg = RefNonBlanks(irg)
        
        ' Lock the non-blank changed target cells.
        If Not iurg Is Nothing Then
            ' Note how you don't need to unprotect earlier!
            .Unprotect Password:=P_WORD
            iurg.Locked = True
            .Protect Password:=P_WORD
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub

Help: Standard Module, e.g. Module1 (or the same sheet module)
Function RefNonBlanks(ByVal rg As Range) As Range
    
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) > 0 Then
            If IsFirstFound Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
            Else
                Set urg = cell
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
        
    If IsFirstFound Then Set RefNonBlanks = urg
        
End Function

Bonus: The same sheet module

You might find the following useful while developing (testing) your code.

Private Sub UnlockAll()
    With Me
        .Unprotect Password:="1214"
        .Range("C54:G150").Locked = False
        .Protect Password:="1214"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub LockNonBlanks()
    
    With Me
        
        Dim urg As Range: Set urg = RefNonBlanks(.Range("C54:G150"))
        
        If Not urg Is Nothing Then
            .Unprotect Password:="1214"
            urg.Locked = True
            .Protect Password:="1214"
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub

